# error when i import android eclipse project in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Hello guys i'm gald to be here, please i have that error, can you help me?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
```

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1] C:\Users\Khalil\StudioProjects\Android eBook Template\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\10.2.1\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.play_services" to force usage

what i can do?

Comment: change your min sdk version to 14.then it will work

Answer (score 0):

In your `Manifest.xml` file, update `uses-sdk` to version 14.

Comment: Add this line: `tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.play_services"`

Also, update Google Play Services in app level build.gradle:
`com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2`

Reference: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

Comment: I got many errors adding this on manifest Error:(183) Attribute "background" already defined with incompatible format.

Comment: Error:(183) Attribute "background" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(13) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(347) Attribute "navigationMode" already defined with incompatible

Answer (score 0):

First Remove the google play library(in this case com.google.android.gms.play_services), then open manifests --> AndroidManifest.xml
and change min sdk version to 14

This Line:- android:minSdkVersion="14"

Also Change it in your build.gradle of app.. 
under the  defaultConfig

Hope it helps!!